# NGINX - expires headers doesn't work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, browser-cache, pagespeed

I'm running a nginx reverse proxy for speeding things up, I built it by source with `ngx_pagespeed`. This works so far. I got several problems with browser caching.

Here is my location block:

```
location / {

    expires 1y;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    index default.aspx

    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_pass http://xxxxxx.xxxx/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_connect_timeout 180;
    proxy_send_timeout 180;
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
}
```

Images are always served with a expires header of "6 days", I tried it already with another location block (nested an unnested):

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|gif|svg|svgz|woff|woff2|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;}
```

I tried to figure out if the page speed module could set this header, but no luck so far. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself. It was a mess up between pagespeed and nginx cache. I disabled the nginx proxy cache and now it works.

Comment: can you share the config/code example that worked?